# Cocos2d HOWTO access CCNode using getChildByTag from another class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Could someone help me, I am trying to access a CCLabelTTF that resides in a CCLayer subclass(GameLayer), but I want to access it from another Player class(also a CCLayer). I thought

`[self getChildByTag: DEBUG_LABEL];`

searches the scene and finds the object that matches it and returns a pointer to it, since all objects are stored in a tree data structure.

I was able to access the label through trial and error using the follwing code but would appreciate if someone could advise if I am not understanding the `getChildByTag` method or if there is a way of searching the scene for an object without using the code below.

```
CCLabelTTF *lbl = (CCLabelTTF *)[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] getChildByTag: GAME_LAYER_TAG] getChildByTag: DEBUG_LABEL_TAG];
```

Please advise.

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/09/strategies-accessing-cocos2d-nodes-scene-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getChildByTag` only checks direct children of the parent `CCNode` calling it. It will not check children's children (grandchildren, if you will).

For example, if your node hierarchy looks like this:

MyCCLayer1->MyCCLayer2->MyCCSprite->MyCCLabel

Calling MyCCLayer1 only has direct access to MyCCLayer2 via the `getChildByTag` call. In turn, MyCCLayer2 could call `getChildByTag` to get MyCCSprite, and then MyCCSprite could call `getChildByTag` to get MyCCLabel.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Through some testing I also got to the same conclusion. Just wanted to verify if my understanding was correct or I was doing something wrong. I've used some other game engines/libraries that allow searching the entire tree structure (Box2D). Maybe I was starting from that perspective, although there is a little performance hit probing the entire tree the option was there.